# Return true/false in recursive SQL query based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchy, recursive-query

I have the following flowchart. Hopefully, it's self-explanatory

On top of the hierarchy there's a request that is a basic parent of all the request below it. Requests below have the **'id', 'parent_id', 'state'** fields

[image]

My final goal is to find out whether at least one of the parent's sub-request has **illegal/not-legit** states. There are a few 'not-legit' states - that's why I'm using `NOT IN`. So, I need to simply return true/false, if at least one sub-request has the wrong state

I use the query below to build the hierarchy

```
DECLARE @main_parent_id bigint = 1

; with cte 
    as (select id
        from tbl_request as rH 
        WHERE id = @main_parent_id
        UNION ALL
        select rH.id 
        from tbl_request as rH 
        join cte
        on rH.parent_id = cte.id
       WHERE rH.state NOT IN('not-legit'))
    select *
    from cte
    order by id;
```

But I don't know how to return true/false instead of just returning id's. In addition `@main_parent_id` is a dynamic variable that comes from another SELECT which returns all requests that are on top of the hierarchy.

In a sense, the query above should return `true` if all sub-requests are in `LEGIT` states, `false` if there's at least one sub-request in `NOT-LEGIT` state.

For your convenience, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd169a/19)

Comment: That sounds like a query for `IF EXISTS`/`IF NOT EXISTS` - so if one record exists in the non-legit states, select 0, else select 1

Comment: your first and biggest issue is that youre filtering out not legit. How can you compare against a thing youre telling the compiler to leave out? Second you can easily handle this in the final select from the output of the cte

Comment: Thanks for posting the code and the sql fiddle! Your existing code doesn't seem to quite line up with your intention though. Right now you are building a hierarchy consisting only of requests that are "legit". But this won't help you determine whether "at least one of the parent's sub requests is not legit". So it's not so much a question about returning ID's, as a question about how to "parse" the hierarchy as a whole. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Stop searching a branch when a non-legit is already found.

```
with cte 
    as (select id, state
        from tbl_request as rH 
        WHERE id = @main_parent_id
        UNION ALL
        select rH.id, rH.state
        from tbl_request as rH 
        join cte
          on rH.parent_id = cte.id
             and (cte.state is null or cte.state NOT IN('not-legit'))
       )
    select case when exists(select 1 from cte where  cte.state IN('not-legit'))
        then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer

Could you please tell me how to use it with an `AND` statement?

Comment: ... AND exists(select 1 from cte where  cte.state IN('not-legit')) ..

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
DECLARE @main_parent_id bigint = 1

;with cte as (
  select id, state
  from tbl_request as rH 
  WHERE id = @main_parent_id
  UNION ALL
  select rH.id, rh.state
  from tbl_request as rH 
    join cte
      on rH.parent_id = cte.id
)
select
  case when (select top 1 1 from cte where state = 'not-legit') = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end as NonLegit
```

Answer (score -1):

Here try this, I just tested it and it works

Part of the problem was you were filtering out the not-legit. Second you can use CASE WHEN to test for the presence of 'not-legit.'

```
; WITH cte as 
    (
        SELECT id, state
        FROM tbl_request AS rH 
        WHERE id = @main_parent_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT rH.id, rh.state 
        FROM tbl_request AS rH 
        INNER JOIN cte ON rH.parent_id = cte.id
    )
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN SUM
        (
            CASE WHEN state='not-legit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        )>0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END
    FROM cte
  ;
```