# Using SQL recursive query as AND statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchy, recursive-query

I have the following flowchart. Hopefully, it's self-explanatory

On top of the hierarchy there's a request that is a basic parent of all the request below it. Requests below have the **'id', 'parent_id', 'state'** fields

[image]

My final goal is to find all parents ids that satisfy all AND statements including the last one (hierarchical query). However, I don't know how to use it as an AND statement.

The hierarchical query looks like this:

```
with cte 
    as (select id, state
        from tbl_request as rH 
        WHERE id = /* each id from the very first select */
        UNION ALL
        select rH.id, rH.state
        from tbl_request as rH 
        join cte
          on rH.parent_id = cte.id
             and (cte.state is null or cte.state NOT IN('not-legit'))
       )
    select case when exists(select 1 from cte where  cte.state IN('not-legit'))
        then 1 else 0 end
```

Expectantly, it does what it's supposed to

The solution was suggested in the question

[Return true/false in recursive SQL query based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033132/return-true-false-in-recursive-sql-query-based-on-condition)

For your convenience, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd169a/38)

Comment: So if it does what it's supposed to - what is the question here??

Comment: I meant the hierarchical query does what it's supposed to. But I need to merge it with the very first select

Comment: With which query you want to merge the above one?

Comment: @NishantGupta The first query can be found in the provided SQL Fiddle

Comment: "all parents ids that satisfy all AND statements including the last one (hierarchical query)". I don't understand this predicate. What and statements? What do you mean by "the last one"? What is the meaning of "the very first select"? Why do you even need the recursive CTE anyway, can't you just query `tbl_request` directly? I think you should describe your actual requirement in full. "I have a table of requests, `tbl_request`. I need to _, but I'm having trouble with _", fill in the blanks.

Comment: I have a table of requests, `tbl_request`. I need to `merge all AND queries including the hierarchical one`, but I'm having trouble with `merging them all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've worked out what you want.

You need to recurse through all the nodes and their children, returning its `state` and its ultimate root `parent_id`.

Then aggregate by that ID and exclude any group that contains a row with `state = 'not-legit'`. In other words, flip the logic to a double negative.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rH.id, rH.state, rH.id AS top_parent
        FROM tbl_request as rH 
        WHERE (rH.state is null or rH.state <> 'not-legit')
          AND rH.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rH.id, rH.state, cte.top_parent
        FROM tbl_request as rH
        JOIN cte
          ON rH.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT top_parent
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    cte.top_parent
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN cte.state = 'not-legit' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

> You could also change the logic back to a positive, but it would need to look like this:
> `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN cte.state is null or cte.state <> 'not-legit' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)`
> In other words, there are the same number of these filtered rows as there are all rows.
> This feels more complex than what I have put above.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd169a/43)

Comment: Well, since there's one sub-request in `not-legit` state, the query shouldn't return anything. But this query returns one. That's why I want to use CTE just as plain `AND` statement.

Comment: You're right, I didn't fully understand your logic. Have edited

Comment: Thank you very much

Where should I put all the other `AND's` and the `INNER JOIN` that I wrote in the fiddle?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd169a/38

Comment: I don''t see any in your fiddle. You do have a comment at the top about joins, I suppose place them in the anchor part of the CTE (before `UNION ALL`)

Comment: `/* there's also an INNER JOIN (hopefully, it won't be an obstacle) */` and `/* a lot of AND statements */`

It's a comment in the fiddle

Comment: Anyway, I sorted it out myself
Here's a new twist though. There are not-legit states for `sub-requests` and for `parent request` - 2 different sets. Would you be so kind to tell me on how to modify the query to accomplish that?

Comment: The first `WHERE (rH.state is null or rH.state <> 'not-legit')` is for the parent. The `HAVING` is for the children

Comment: Thank you for clarification, your query did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Replace your

```
WHERE id = /* each id from the very first select */
```

by

```
WHERE id in (
    SELECT r.id FROM tbl_request AS r
    /* there's also an INNER JOIN (hopefully, it won't be an obstacle) */
    WHERE r.parent_id is null
    /* a lot of AND statements */
  )
```

Also, you should use UNION instead of UNION ALL, since there is no point using duplicated tuples (`id` and `state`) in this case.

To summarize, your query should look like this one

```
with cte 
    as (select id, state
        from tbl_request as rH 
        WHERE id in (

           SELECT r.id
             FROM tbl_request AS r
                  /* there's also an INNER JOIN (hopefully, it won't be an obstacle) */
            WHERE r.parent_id is null
                  /* a lot of AND statements */

        ) UNION
        select rH.id, rH.state
        from tbl_request as rH 
        join cte
          on rH.parent_id = cte.id
             and (cte.state is null or cte.state NOT IN('not-legit'))
       )
```

Your subquery can contain any inner joins or any number of AND operators you need, as long as it returns one column (`select r.id`) it will work fine.